# Is it okay to use Junit Assert API in Java production code

Tags: java, exception, junit, illegalargumentexception

I want to do null checks for my method arguments, like parameters should not be null. Is it okay to use something like this `assertNotNull("Map should not be null", filePaths);` in my Java code?
I'm trying to avoid

```
if(filePaths == null){
  throw new IllegalArgumentException("Maps cannot be null");
}
```

just to keep my code clean from all those null checks. I know I can write a `Validator` class of my own and have overloaded `notNull` methods but is there something existing and simple to use to not re-invent the wheel.

The only drawback I see of using `JUnit` `Assert` is that it throws `AssertionError` and not `IllegalArgumentException` and so forth.

Comment: Why not use Guava's [`Preconditions`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/release/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Preconditions.html)?

Comment: Another option is to use the assert keyword provided by the Java language -- e.g., assert null != filepaths : "Maps cannot be null". These checks can be turned on or off on startup.

Comment: @AndyThomas: _Do not use assertions for argument checking in public methods._ from [Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/assert.html). If assertions are disabled, it will never be called

Comment: @LouisWasserman: Thanks for your advice, we are not currently using `Guava`, but it looks like worth giving shot

Comment: @Learner - Good point. In some special cases I've used assert() for non-public methods. But usually it would be better to stick to a single approach, like Louis' suggestion of Guava's Preconditions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it is not OK to use it. The JUnit assert methods throw an [AssertionError](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/AssertionError.html). It's not a good idea to throw [Error](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Error.html) in production code. From the javadoc:

> An Error is a subclass of Throwable that indicates serious problems
>   that a reasonable application should not try to catch. Most such
>   errors are abnormal conditions. The ThreadDeath error, though a
>   "normal" condition, is also a subclass of Error because most
>   applications should not try to catch it. A method is not required to
>   declare in its throws clause any subclasses of Error that might be
>   thrown during the execution of the method but not caught, since these
>   errors are abnormal conditions that should never occur. That is, Error
>   and its subclasses are regarded as unchecked exceptions for the
>   purposes of compile-time checking of exceptions.

Comment: Even if I write my own validation, I'll still be throwing IllegalArgumentException in production code. Oh you meant throw `Exception` and not `Error`

Comment: Correct, I meant don't throw an Error as opposed to an Exception.

Answer (score 13):

If you use Java 7+, you can use:

```
Objects.requireNonNull(filePaths, "Map should not be null");
```

Also with a null argument, I would expect a NullPointerException or an IllegalArgumentException, but not an AssertionError.

Comment: Thanks for your response. We re still on Java 6 but good to know that its in built in Java 7

Comment: @Learner With Java 6 you can use Guava Preconditions as already pointed out (it does roughly the same thing as Objects.requireNonNull).